# Rewrite equivalent of a simple redirect in HAProxy?

Tags: haproxy

I currently have a line in our HAProxy config that I uncomment when I want to put the site into 'maintenance mode'.  It just redirects requests not for the static subdomain to a maintenance page.

```
redirect location http://static.site.com/maintenance.htm unless { hdr(host) -i static.site.com }
```

Of course, this is is a 30x type redirect, so a new http request, and the user sees the url change.

**I'd prefer to simply rewrite the request to another url (so the original url does not change in the browser)**, but can't work out how to do this.  I've tried experimenting with `reqirep`, but perhaps my regex-fu is not up to scratch.

Can anyone suggest a solution? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following rule should suffice:

```
reqirep ^.* http://static.site.com/maintenance.htm
```

[Reference](https://code.google.com/p/haproxy-docs/wiki/reqrep)